# Dreamweaver php mysql url redirection

Tags: php, mysql, url, dreamweaver

I have a row named url in class table Mysql, using dreamweaver with `rsClassInstructor` binding I use the following string

```
"a href=<?php echo $row_rsClassInstructor['url']; ?>"
```

when I click on the link all I get is url with no value

`example www.elearninggurus.net/url` instead of `www.elearninggurus.net/VB.php`

Please help me solve this

Comment: Not sure if you just copied it strangely but your a href tags are all messed up... Would also need more info to resolve issue obviously.

Comment: Ryan code is "a href=<?php echo $row_rsClassInstructor['url']; ?>"

Comment: @user1275363 change to `<a href="<?php echo $row_rsClassInstructor['url']; ?>">`

Comment: Gabriel- I tried <a href="<?php echo $row_rsClassInstructor['url']; ?>"> and  all i got is  http://localhost:8080/elearninggurus/<href="url">

Answer (score 0):

```
"< a href=' <?php echo $row_rsClassInstructor['url']; ?>'"
```

try it href attribute have string value so one s